# Git Hook: Take action when a branch is advanced

Tags: git, hook, githooks

I'm looking to build and publish a latex document every time I advance the tip of a specific branch.

I'm looking at what hook I should be putting my build script and which conditions I need to check for.

Comment: I've been thinking about doing the exact same thing with Git and LaTeX. But I'm afraid of a few things:

1. keeping the PDFs will make my repo size bloat very quickly.
2. LaTeX errors in the source. To make sure everything runs correctly, I'd have to re-pull the archive and check the PDF. Too much work.

Comment: I have a pre-commit hook that rejects any commit that won't build error free. I checkout the index and run my test, essentially -draftmode -halt-on-error and just reject commit if that doesn't exit with 0 status. I don't keep the pdf in the repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably a little late... but you can find out which branch was committed to by using

```
if [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` = "master" ]; then
  ...
fi
```

in you script when you checked out the branch to commit in it.

Comment: i get "remote: [: 4: master: unexpected operator" with that command. Its actually a single '=' sign. I would add to that, for the git beginners like me that you have to use that like this : "if [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` = "master" ]; then
   _git instructions or w/e here_
fi
"

Answer (score 4):

If changes are coming in via a `push` to a remote, then on the remote server you'll want to use the `post-receive` hook (though if you use `pre-receive` then you can reject the push if, say, latex fails).

If you're using your local repository you should use `post-commit` (or `pre-commit` if you want to be able to reject the commit).

The hooks are documented in the [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) man page.

Comment: In my post-commit, how to i find out which branch was committed to?

Comment: Oh also, will this trigger on a merge or fast-forward?